# Convert pandas dataframe column with xml data to normalised columns?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, data-analysis

I have a `DataFrame` in `pandas`, one of whose columns is a XML string. What I want to do is create one column for each of the xml nodes with column names in a normalised form. For example,

```
    id    xmlcolumn
    1     <main attr1='abc' attr2='xyz'><item><prop1>text1</prop1><prop2>text2</prop2></item></main>
    2     <main ........</main>
```

I want to convert this to a data frame like so:

```
id   main.attr1  main.attr2 main.item.prop1  main.item.prop2
1       abc        xyz          text1           text2
2      .....
```

How would I do that, while still keeping the existing columns in the `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

The first step that needs to be done is to convert the XML string to a pandas `Series` (under the assumption, that there will always be the same amount of columns in the end). So you need a function like:

```
def convert_xml(raw):
    # some etree xml mangling
```

This can be achieved e.g. using the [etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.htm) package in python. The returned series must have an index, where each entry in the index is the new column name to appear, e.g. for your example:

```
pd.Series(['abc', 'xyz'], index=['main.attr1', 'main.attr2'])
```

Given this function, you can do the following with pandas (mocking away the XML mangling):

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'keep': [42], 'xml': '<foo></foo>'})
temp = frame['xml'].apply(convert_xml)
frame = frame.drop('xml', axis=1)
frame = pd.concat([frame, temp], axis=1)
```